# Issue with Sinatra for getting the response for a GET request for a ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ROR application which wants to GET the contents from a URI through the REST mechanism. Although the URI is able to get the response back when the URI is used in the browser or through the curl. But when sent through the ROR application, it gives the following response: { "error": "\n\n\n \n\n\n  Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty. \n  \n \n Try this:\n get '/works' do\n  \"Hello World\"\nend \n  \n\n\n", "status": 404 }. Can someone please help what might be the possible reason for getting such issues with the GET request.

```
def get_result(url, options = { content_type: 'json' }) 
uri = URI.parse(url) options[:headers] ||= {} 
options[:headers]['Host'] = uri.host 
conn = faraday_conn(options[:content_type], options) 
..... 
if options[:data] 
response = conn.post url, {}, options[:headers] do |request| 
request.body = options[:data] 
end 
else response = conn.get url, {}, options[:headers] 
end
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the RoR application that makes the request?

Comment: def get_result(url, options = { content_type: 'json' })
      uri = URI.parse(url)
      options[:headers] ||= {}
      options[:headers]['Host'] = uri.host

      conn = faraday_conn(options[:content_type], options)
      .....
      if options[:data]
        response = conn.post url, {}, options[:headers] do |request|
          request.body = options[:data]
        end
      else
        response = conn.get url, {}, options[:headers]
      end

Comment: Hi Steve, was the code useful?

Comment: Hi, could you edit the question and include the code there?  And use the option to mark the snippet as a code sample (the "{}" option on the edit bar of the question.

Comment: Hi Steve.. I have edited the question. I debugged the code after this, and I can find that the GET request sent and the URI is being sent properly through the socket connection. But some how the response received from the HOST (which is a website in this case) is (status: 404 Faraday:ResourceNotFound error alongwith the Sinatra error message which I have mentioned in the question